# How could I animate truck inside of slideshow?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an image that look like this: [image]
And I'm trying to animate this truck on my slideshow. Early I was trying to combine my slide show with [this](https://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/KwBWJd) example, but it didnt work. The idea is that when slide turns to "free shipping" slide truck will move from right side to left (where it placed right now). Is there any way I can do it? And this slide show I modified from [here](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css">
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="animation/car_anim.js"></script>
  <style>
  .carousel-inner > .item > img,
  .carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
      width: 100%;
      margin: auto;
  }
  #Image_Car
{
      position:absolute;
       overflow: hidden;
    margin:60px 8px;
    left: -120px;
}

  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <br>
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">


    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="img/hand.jpg" alt="Chania" width="977" height="230">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="img/shipping.jpg" alt="Chania" width="977" height="230">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="img/hand.jpg" alt="Flower" width="977" height="230">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="img/hand.jpg" alt="Flower" width="977" height="230">
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
/* Demo Scripts for Bootstrap Carousel and Animate.css article
* on SitePoint by Maria Antonietta Perna
*/
(function( $ ) {

    //Function to animate slider captions 
    function doAnimations( elems ) {
        //Cache the animationend event in a variable
        var animEndEv = 'webkitAnimationEnd animationend';

        elems.each(function () {
            var $this = $(this),
                $animationType = $this.data('animation');
            $this.addClass($animationType).one(animEndEv, function () {
                $this.removeClass($animationType);
            });
        });
    }

    //Variables on page load 
    var $myCarousel = $('#carousel-example-generic'),
        $firstAnimatingElems = $myCarousel.find('.item:first').find("[data-animation ^= 'animated']");


    //Animate captions in first slide on page load 
    doAnimations($firstAnimatingElems);

    //Pause carousel  
    $myCarousel.carousel('pause');


    //Other slides to be animated on carousel slide event 
    $myCarousel.on('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {
        var $animatingElems = $(e.relatedTarget).find("[data-animation ^= 'animated']");
        doAnimations($animatingElems);
    });  

})(jQuery);
</script>
<script>


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at animate.css at https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/

They provide a lot of ready made animations. Just add the css classes `animated` and `slideInLeft` to the truck, at the appropriate moment (for example `window.onload`)

You could also preload like so:

```
var img = new Image()
img.src = 'http://some-url/some-image'
img.addEventListener('load', function() {
    // add .animate and .slideInLeft css classes
    // or just use jQuery to register the event handler
})
```

Hopefully i inspired you :-)